# Google Map - saving latitude and longitude of route/path to my server to show in future the selected route/path and navigate accordingly

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, latitude-longitude, google-maps-api

I am planning a software/mobile application where the tasks are like below.

1. An interface where a admin person will create a route map customisation by dragging a polygon path and also may add google suggested shortest path. So by combining both path software will save all latitude and longitude in server.
2. Later, when any user will go to that path he will see the customised path and can navigate.

We are using Google licensed version. My point is there is some privacy policy in Google like below

[image]
[image]

So my question is if I save latitude and longitude only does it violet the Google privacy policy?

If violet then what will be approaches to achieve my goal?